# Register Platform Device in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, ntp

I'm trying to use the pps-gpio module for an NTP time server on an embedded Linux platform (Olimex imx233) and need to register a GPIO pin as a platform device. I've gathered from googling that I need to create a platform_device struct and use platform_device_register(pdev) to register the pin. Most documentation says this is normally done when the board is initialized, but I can't find where I would even put a call to platform_device_register to initialize this. Is it even necessary to register the device during startup, or can I just execute C code to register the device from console? My plan would be then to use modprobe to load the module that needs the device after that has been done.

Sorry if this is a non-sensical question, I had no experience working with Linux drivers until two days ago and Google has been my greatest teacher so far! Thanks

Comment: If your platform and Linux kernel supports device tree, you can define a node for pps-gpio as documented here. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pps/pps-gpio.txt You will not need to add `platform_device` since that would require a kernel rebuild.

Comment: pps-gpio wasn't selected in the kernel configuration I have, so I have to recompile anyway I think.

Comment: I will try to add the node to the device tree and see how that goes.